# Dot after variable to show all the available functions doesn't work on my mac

Tags: python, function, dask

I saw a presentation on Dask (written in Python). The presenter used dot after a variable of Dask to show all the available functions. But it doesn't work for my local machine.
Can anyone help me understand how to make it work? I wish to learn this to improve my coding efficiency.
[image]

Comment: That's called intellisense.  You should be able to trigger it by using `CTRL+SPACE` after typing the period.

Comment: This seems like tab-auto completion on the IPython interpreter. To get the list of available functions, you type in `a.` and press tab.

Comment: Tab-completion is also available in the standard Python interactive interpreter. It's enabled by default in Python 3, but you need to enable it in Python 2 (that can be automated via a startup script, as explained in the tutorial).

Comment: Thanks a lot TheIncorrigible1, Tomothy32 and PM 2Ring for the answers!